# Fluid variables do not read the child values anymore. (TYPO3 9.5.*)

Tags: object, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

So i have a table which lists some appointments. These appointments belong to an event. The goal here is to list all the appointments and get the information of the event that they belong to.

So far everything works fine until i try to get the information of the event. I get an object which looks like this:

[image]

Now if i use something like this : `{appointment.event.title}` it will give back `NULL`.

That means that it doesnt access the properties. **In TYPO3 v8 it works perfectly, but not in TYPO3 v9.**

If i activate the `<f:debug>{appointment}</f:debug>` and get the whole object as debugged, then this `{appointment.event.title}` works! I can get the title.

The question now is what have changed since TYPO3 8 and can not access these properties anymore and how can i regain access?

In use: TYPO3 v9

Mode: Composer

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

Thanks to [@Claus Due](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162619/claus-due) i visited my Model to see if the getters und setters are there. They were there BUT before my getter, the `@lazy` parameter was present. After i removed, everything worked as it should.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems bug of TYPO3 version 9

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the following is true:

1. You forgot to add a getter method for the property you try to access and you are confusing the output of `f:debug` with what is *actually* gettable from the object. The debug ViewHelper outputs also protected properties.
2. You constructed the model object with `__call` or `__get` so you are affected by https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/pull/438 which is solved but not yet released (current Fluid version is 2.6.0, patch will be included in next version).

You don't say which TYPO3 version you use, nor if you are using composer, so it's hard to tell if your versions of Fluid are the same - they should be, since both TYPO3 v8 and TYPO3 v9 use the same external Fluid library.

The solution in either case is to add proper getter methods to your domain model object and always remember that the output of `f:debug` does not 100% correspond to what you can actually access: `f:debug` will for example not show virtual getter methods that don't have a property associated with it.

Comment: I have an action which calls the event and gets all the information right. If i call the same object but through the appointment repository (appointment action ) i dont get them. My getters are there. But i can not access them

Comment: If you are also unable to access those properties in your controller action (PHP code) it is clearly a problem with the model. If it's different when you load the object from repository vs map it as controller argument, that clearly indicates a problem with the repository (perhaps an improperly overridden method, wrong Query preparation, etc.). But perhaps you can explain a bit more about the context. What is the source code of the model? Which version of v8 and v9 did you use? What else did you change (because you probably updated extensions, too?). And did you check that GitHub issue...?